# White space under navigation bar in drawer

Tags: dart, flutter

I encountered an annoying styling issue where if I opened my drawer I would get white space under the navigation bar on Android. Whereas if I wasn't in the drawer it would display the correct color just fine.

[image: Screenshot of app outlining the stylistic error]

I'm using the following code for my drawer widget:

```
drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new  ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountEmail: new Text("juhlinus@gmail.com"),
            accountName: new Text("Linus Juhlin"),
            currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            child: new Text("LJ"),
            ),
            otherAccountsPictures: <Widget>[
            new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                child: new Text("MH"),
            )
            ],
        ),
        new ListTile(
            title: new Text("Artiklar"),
            leading: new Icon(Icons.web),
        ),
        new ListTile(
            title: new Text("Media"),
            leading: new Icon(Icons.wallpaper),
        ),
        new Divider(),
        new ListTile(
            title: new Text("Inställningar"),
            leading: new Icon(Icons.settings)
        ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Comment: FWIW I think there is some kind of `$ flutter screenshot` command. I haven't used it, but it seem relevant given your image above

Comment: Thanks! That improves the visibility greatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that in source code of Flutter *UserAccountsDrawerHeader* bottom margin is 8.0 by default.
That's why you see this white thin space under header.

So the solution will be setting the bottom margin equal zero:

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
...
```

Works fine, without any tricks.

Comment: Thanks for the research! I've gone ahead and changed your answer to the accepted one, since it better explains the reason for the behavior in my question, as well as a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

After some tinkering I figured that it must have been the padding, I tried to remove all padding from the ListView Widget and that did the trick.

**I simply added the padding to the ListView like so:**

```
[...]
child: new  ListView(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    children: <Widget>[
[...]
```

Hope this helps anyone stumbling upon this themselves.